# MLE for an ellipse

Tags: maximum-likelihood, geometry

I'm not at all a statistician, but in the course of my work I've come across a non-trivial maximum likelihood estimation problem, and I'm looking for ideas and/or references on how to approach it.  The problem is this:

> Points $(x,y)$ are drawn randomly according to
> $$\begin{eqnarray*}
> x & = & c_x + \sin(\theta + \phi)\\
> y & = & c_y + \sin(\theta)
> \end{eqnarray*}
> $$
> where $c_x$ and $c_y$ are normally distributed with mean zero and unknown variances, $\theta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$, and $\phi$ is fixed but unknown.  Given many such points $(x,y)$, how can I estimate $\phi$ and the variances of $c_x$ and $c_y$?

Qualitatively, this model places points randomly around an ellipse, with ellipticity determined by $\phi$.  The random variables $c_{x,y}$ serve to thicken the ellipse.  Actually, this model is a slight simplification of what I'm really working with--in the real model both the amplitude of the $\sin$ terms and $\phi$ also have random components--but I reckon if I can do the above problem then that's good progress.

I've taken a crack at doing the integrals for a direct MLE of the parameters, but it's quite difficult, even numerically.  So I figured I should consult experts: **Is there an efficient solution to this problem?**  E.g. perhaps there is some sort of Monte Carlo method for doing this kind of problem?

---

Edit: It has been suggested that this problem is the same as ellipse fitting.  This is incorrect.  As explained in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.76.033613) (which is where this question is derived from), ellipse fitting gives a biased estimate of $\phi$ and the variances in the above problem.  The paper explicitly states that the above MLE problem gives a superior estimate than ellipse fitting.  Ellipse fitting is not what this question is asking for.

Comment: Consider that for a given $\phi$, the optimal $\theta$ are those that result in points on the ellipse that are closest to the corresponding $x,y$ in terms of some distance function (e.g. Gaussian loss with diagonal variances). So the problem is to find values of $\theta$/variances that make the ellipse "close" in some sense to the data. This is actually a well studied problem in computer vision, referred to as "ellipse fitting" or "elliptical regression". It is usually framed in terms of least squares, see for example http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mdailey/Face-Coord/ellipse-specific-fitting.pdf ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I believe this question has been marked a duplicate in error.  The linked question concerns ellipse fitting, and I have edited the question body to explain why this is a distinct problem.  As explained in the referenced paper, the whole point of setting up the problem as a MLE is to do better than ellipse fitting.

Comment: Some parts of this edit look confusing: in what sense is $\theta$ "estimated," given it is random?  Did you mean $\phi$ is estimated?  Do you observe $\theta$ or not?  Given that $\phi$ parameterizes a family of ellipses and you are estimating $\phi,$ in what sense is this *not* ellipse fitting?

Comment: @whuber $\theta$ was a typo, I meant $\phi$; thanks for catching that.  My understanding is that ellipse fitting parametrizes the ellipse a different way, as in this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268974/ellipse-formula-from-points  This results in a biased estimate of $\phi$, which is the quantity of interest here.

Comment: Right: I appreciate that the different parameterization results in a different probability distribution of the points (which is why I reopened this question).  I just wanted to make sure that was your meaning.